# Flash Builder 4.7 SWF not updating upon compilation. How to force compile a brand new SWF?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I can no longer use Flash Builder as my code changes are not picked up and packaged into a new SWF. I am debugging with a stand alone player.

The problem happens if the debugger encounters an error. Commenting out the offending line will produce the same error, meaning that upon compilation the SWF wasn't updated with the new code.

Removing the SWF so that it builds from fresh does not work. The error in this case says that the SWF could not be found.

I have updated to use the newest versions on the AIR SDK (4.0) and stand alone Flash Player (14.0) and Flash Builder is using them successfully.

Is there a way to force the creation of a brand new SWF file?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project via Project > Clean, then rebuilding?

Comment: yes, tried that, thanks - EDIT... actually, after deleting the SWF file then pressing Project > Clean it has reinstated it freshly. Maybe the problem is caused by SVN then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that problem too especially when linking to external project/source code. FB gets confused and upon error does not refresh anything anymore.

You can force FB to refresh that way:

- close the debugger if the app is still running.
- delete the swf in bin-debug
- refresh the project then do a "clean"
- a new swf should be created and FB should have refreshed itself.

I still haven't found a way to avoid this problem when using external source code.

Comment: Seriously, I do all the steps here and it still loads the previous swf, which I have no idea is coming from. Some kind of cache.

Answer (score 0):

Reposting my comment as answer, since it worked (kinda).

In the menubar, go to project, then clean.

This is also the method [adobe describes for making a clean build](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fef.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb524b8220812e5611f28f-7fd2).

Comment: Doing just a clean doesn't work everytime that's the problem especially for big project. FB sometimes will never update if the swf is not deleted and on big projects clean doesn't work if refresh did not run once before.

Comment: ... Personally, I just use FlashDevelop anyway, haven't had any troubles with that, save for particularily nasty exceptions requiring you to kill the debugger via task manager.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. In my case .flexLipProperties file was broken and the class I was editing was not included in project build.

You can force FB to include your file by adding it to Flex build path.

If your project is flex library project.

1. Clean your project
2. Open project properties -> Flex library build path -> select all target classes
3. Build target project

If your project is flex project.

1. Open project properties -> Flex Modules -> Add target module if it's missing from the list
2. Build target project